# Gettext doesnt work what I'm doing wrong?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm making small plugin to share the post in my word-press

Everything work but I can't get a string to be translatable throw wpml.

Bear with me it's not a question about wpml,
**My problem is that I can't figure how to add Get text to my code in the right way.**

Here is my code:

```
function add_social_share_icons($content)
{
   
    $html = "<div class='social-share-wrapper'><div class='share-on'>Share on: </div>";

    global $post;

    $url = get_permalink($post->ID);
    $url = esc_url($url);

    if(get_option("social-share-facebook") == 1)
    {
        $html = $html . "<div class='facebook'><a target='_blank' href='http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=" . $url . "'>Facebook</a></div>";
    }
```

I want to translate this "Share on:" the wpml use the Gettext to detect the string.

Like this `<th><?php echo __('Due date:', 'themedomain'); ?></th>`

I tried something like this:

```
$html = "<div class='social-share-wrapper'><div class='share-on'><?php _e('Share on:'); ?></div>";
```

But it doesn't work!

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't embed a function like that into a string, only simple things can be done that way. Instead, you want to concatenate which can be done in a couple of ways, but this is probably the easiest. Also, instead of `_e()` which echos the text, I'm using [`__()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/__/) to just translate

```php
$html = "<div class='social-share-wrapper'><div class='share-on'>" . __('Share on:') . "</div>";
```

The second parameter of `__()` is the text domain, same as `_e()`